# Insert Links in Lotus Notes Email

Tags: lotus-notes

I am rather new to Lotus Notes as a user, but I receive emails often from people with links to databases, trouble tickets, etc., and uses a little icon of a document to click.

I can't seem to figure out how the heck to do it, don't even know what the correct terminology is so having trouble Googling it.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Right click on a document, and select "Copy as Document Link"... Then just paste the link.

Answer (score 2):

You can either paste a link from another document (right click and select copy document link) or highlight an section on your message and select create/hotspot from the menu.